# error -Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I was trying to write a mapreduce code in java.So here are my files.

mapper class(bmapper):

```
public class bmapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,NullWritable>{
    private String txt=new String();
    public void mapper(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String str =value.toString(); 
        int index1 = str.indexOf("TABLE OF CONTENTS");
        int index2 = str.indexOf("</table>");
        int index3 = str.indexOf("MANAGEMENT'S DISCUSSION AND ANALYSIS");

        if(index1 == -1)    
        {   txt ="nil";
        }
        else
        {
           if(index1<index3 && index2>index3)
           {
               int index4 = index3+ 109;
              int pageno =str.charAt(index4);
              String[] pages =str.split("<page>");
             txt = pages[pageno+1];
           }
           else
           {
               txt ="nil";

           }
        }

        context.write(new Text(txt), NullWritable.get());
    } 

}
```

reducer class(breducer):

```
public class breducer extends Reducer<Text,NullWritable,Text,NullWritable>{

    public void reducer(Text key,NullWritable value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{

        context.write(key, value);

    }

}
```

driver class (bdriver):

```
public class bdriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJobName("black coffer");
        job.setJarByClass(bdriver.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setReducerClass(breducer.class);
        job.setMapperClass(bmapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path[]{new Path(args[0])});
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}
```

`

I am getting following error.

```
[training@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar blackcoffer.jar com.test.bdriver /page1.txt /MROUT4
18/03/16 04:38:56 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
18/03/16 04:38:57 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
18/03/16 04:38:57 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library is available
18/03/16 04:38:57 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
18/03/16 04:38:57 INFO snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library loaded
18/03/16 04:38:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201803151041_0007
18/03/16 04:38:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
18/03/16 04:39:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201803151041_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recieved org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:871)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:574)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I think it is not able to find Mapper and reducer class. I have written the code in main class, It is getting default Mapper and reducer class

Comment: Please fix your code formatting. Please describe what you're trying to do, what isn't working (including full error message) and what you tried to solve it. Right now it's not clear what you're asking, you just posted some code.

Comment: I had fixed my code now.Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question! I unfortunately cannot help you, I never worked with hadoop, I was just reviewing new user questions, but I am sure someone else will. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: @Khush Which version of `hadoop` are you using?

Comment: @Khush could you try using the older API

Comment: @gyan currently i am using hadoop-0.20-conf-pseudo.

Comment: @gyan But my other programs are working just fine having exactly same keyin,keyout,valuein,valueout.can you please tell me more specific reason which i might be facing?

Comment: Did not get you? You have "exactly the same program" running fine on the same machine? Is it possible to try old API and let me know the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input/output type seems compatible with job configuration.

*Adding the issue detail and resolution here (As per discussion in the comments, it is confirmed by OP that the issue resolved).*

As per [Javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html), The reducer's reduce method is having below signature

```
protected void reduce(KEYIN key,
          Iterable<VALUEIN> values,
          org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context context)
               throws IOException,
                      InterruptedException
```

According to it, reducer should be

```
public class breducer extends Reducer<Text,NullWritable,Text,NullWritable>{
    @Overwrite
    public void reducer(Text key,Iterable<NullWritable> value,Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        // Your logic
    }
}
```

The issue was that because of slight difference in the signature of `map()` and `reduce()` method, the methods were not actually getting `overriden`. It was just `overloading` the same method names.

The issue was caught after putting `@Override` annotation on the `map()` and `reduce()` function. Although its not mandatory, but as a best practice, always add `@Override` annotation on implemented `map()` and `reduce()` methods.

Comment: thank you for your solution but this isn't working. can you suggest me something else?

Comment: @khush Is it the same exception?

Comment: Can you please do one thing, put `@Override` annotation on both `map` and `reduce` . I am suspecting, if you are actually overriding the hook methods.

Comment: Was this issue with incorrect method signature in `Reducer`? Because I see that the `reducer` is expected to have a **list** of mapper output in 2nd parameter.

Comment: No ,I had put @Override annotation in map only leaving reduce as it was.

Comment: Is your reducer working? The actual reducer signature is `protected void reduce(KEYIN key,   Iterable<VALUEIN> values,Context context)`. See 2nd parameter, it is an `Iterable` (Kind of list of `NullWritable` for your case).

Comment: yes its been working all right now  as i had done desired changes in the reducer.Thanks for your help.

Comment: @khush Thanks for confirming. Could you please upvote/accept the answer?